# Detect hangup event when call is parked in Asterisk 11

Tags: asterisk

Is there any way to detect a hangup event in dialplan when call is parked? I see this message in log:

> features.c:   == SIP/CHANNAME got tired of being parked

A 'h' extension in context 'parkedcalls' doesn't work:

> [parkedcalls]
>
> ```
> exten => h,1,DumpChan()
> ```

A 'h' extension in main context works, but there is no difference between hangup and pickup.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set up a hangup handler, which follows the channel:
https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Hangup+Handlers

Answer (score 0):

You can check events in AMI or do your own parking via dialplan(pretty trivial).